# Brew update breaks openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, homebrew, rvm

today I wanted to install a new Ruby version through RVM and a homebrew update was triggered which broke OpenSSL.

```
[~]$ rvm install 2.7
.
.
.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.14/x86_64/ruby-2.7.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Updating Homebrew...
==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formulae and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics

==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated Homebrew from 1ea1f31d0 to c0b916764.
Updated 3 taps (homebrew/core, homebrew/cask and homebrew/services).
.
.
.
==> Upgrading 4 outdated packages:
coreutils 8.30_2 -> 8.31
libyaml 0.2.1 -> 0.2.2
openssl@1.1 1.1.1a -> 1.1.1d
readline 8.0.0 -> 8.0.1
==> Upgrading openssl@1.1 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl@1.1-1.1.1d.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/10/104ef018b7bb8fcc49f57e5a60359a28a02d480d85a959e6141394b0571cbb28?__gda__=exp=1578044774~hmac=a692626c1c5fbcfeb1077551a60292afc273163879d04dc708c6051d0fc02d5a&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22openssl%401.1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring openssl@1.1-1.1.1d.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/c_rehash

openssl@1.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because openssl/libressl is provided by macOS so don't link an incompatible version.

If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d: 7,983 files, 17.9MB
==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now...
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1a... (7,953 files, 17.9MB)
Removing: /Users/MyAccount/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libdvdcss... (64B)
Pruned 0 symbolic links and 2 directories from /usr/local
```

When I try to run RAILS I get an openssl connected error:

```
[~]$ rails s
/Users/MyAccount/.rvm/rubies/ruby-x/lib/ruby/x/..../openssl.bundle: dlopen(/Users/MyAccount/.rvm/rubies/ruby-x/lib/ruby/x/..../openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/MyAccount/.rvm/rubies/ruby-x/lib/ruby/x/..../openssl.bundle/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/MyAccount/.rvm/rubies/ruby-x/lib/ruby/x/..../openssl.bundle/openssl.bundle
```

`brew info openssl` gives me:

```
[~]$ brew info openssl
openssl@1.1: stable 1.1.1d (bottled) [keg-only]
Cryptography and SSL/TLS Toolkit
https://openssl.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1a (7,953 files, 17.9MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2019-02-11 at 09:38:06
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d (7,983 files, 17.9MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-01-03 at 15:15:16
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/openssl@1.1.rb
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/c_rehash

openssl@1.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because openssl/libressl is provided by macOS so don't link an incompatible version.

If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Somehow I have two openssl formulas installed in brew: openssl and openssl@1.1. Where openssl has version 1.0.2q and openssl@1.1 versions 1.1.1a and 1.1.1d.

In my .bash_profile I have configured the path:

```
### Customize path for openssl
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

Somehow I am unable to use the upgraded version of openssl: no way to update RVM, reinstall ruby, run rails. The only way I was able get it working is to delete the content of

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d
```

and copy instead the content of

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2q
```

inside.

How can I get it running in a proper way?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to help from the discourse page on brew.sh I was able to find the cause of my problem.

The automatic update of brew and its formulas had overwritten not only the symlink for openssl@1.1 but also the generic openssl link in `/usr/local/opt`. Both pointed now to `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1`, whereas on my second dev system the openssl symlink pointed still to `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl`.

After I recreated the openssl symlink for `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl` everything works again.

The context is that openssl 1.1 is the safest version whereas 1.0 has been deprecated to my knowledge. But in my case it is only to maintain a legacy project in development.

Now I will have one more thing to do after every brew update/upgrade: verify symlinks, after the recent introduction of auto purging of old versions already forces me to copy them back into my system from a backup.

Comment: So, specifically, this is what you did? 

`unlink /usr/local/opt/openssl && ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl /usr/local/opt/openssl`

I have been running into the same issue but this has not solved it as of yet

Comment: It's a hack, but I got around the issue with this solution: https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck/issues/817
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar/`